# Error with ruby version on termux when I try to install metasploit

Tags: ruby, security, console, metasploit, termux

I was installing metasploit with termux and it said:
[termux output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlgJn.jpg)

```
~ $ ls <br>
metasploit-framework  storage  wiki-termux<br>
~ $ cd metasploit-framework<br>
~/metasploit-framework $ ruby msfconsole<br>
Could not find Ascii85-1.1.0 in any of the sources<br>
Run bundle install to install missing gems.<br>
~/metasploit-framework $ bundle install<br>
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........<br>
pcaprub-0.13.0 requires ruby version ~> 2.0, which is incompatible with the<br>
current version, ruby 3.0.0p0<br>
```

And if I try to install metaploit directly:

[termux output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqgsM.jpg)

```
~ $ ls
metasploit-framework  storage  wiki-termux <br>
~ $ cd metasploit-framework <br>
~/metasploit-framework $ msfconsole <br>
The program msfconsole is not installed. Install it by executing: <br>
 pkg install metasploit <br>
~/metasploit-framework $ pkg install metasploit <br>
Checking availability of current mirror: ok <br>
Get:2  https://ipfs.io/ipns/k51qzi5uqu5dj05z8mr958kwvrg7a0wqouj5nnoo5uqu1btnsljvpznfaav9nk unstable InRelease [14.0 kB]<br>
Get:3 https://ipfs.io/ipns/k51qzi5uqu5dgu3homski160l4t4bmp52vb6dbgxb5bda90rewnwg64wnkwxj4 x11 InRelease [14.0 kB]<br>
Get:1 https://10.via0.com/ipns/k51qzi5uqu5dg9vawh923wejqffxiu9bhqlze5f508msk0h7ylpac27fdgaskx stable InRelease<br>
Hit:4 https://grimler.se/game-packages-24 games InRelease <br>
Hit:5 https://grimler.se/science-packages-24 science InRelease <br>
Fetched 42.0 kB in 4s (10.9 kB/s) <br>
Reading package lists... Done <br>
Building dependency tree... Done <br>
Reading state information... Done <br>
All packages are up to date. <br>
Reading package lists... Done <br>
Building dependency tree... Done <br>
Reading state information... Done <br>
E: Unable to locate package metasploit <br>
```

Comment: Please post the actual console output, not images.

Answer (score 0):

termux have removed metasploit and hydra package https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/FAQ#Where_are_Metasploit_and_Hydra_packages

Answer (score 0):

You need Termuxblack for install Ruby2.

First install wget:

```
pkg install wget
```

Now get the Termuxblack install.sh:

```
wget https://github.com/Hax4us/TermuxBlack/raw/master/install.sh
```

Then type

```
sh install.sh
```

Now you can install Ruby2:

```
apt update && apt remove ruby && apt install ruby2
```

Now type 'bundler install' for installing missing gems (you should be in metasploit-framework/ directory.)

Then you can use ./msfconsole or ./msfvenom

If you want make shortcuts:

```
nano /usr/etc/profile.d/bash_aliases.sh
```

Then type the code:

```
alias msfconsole='/$HOME/path to metasploit/msfconsole' alias msfvenom='/$HOME/path to metasploit/msfvenom'
```

Now you can use msfconsole or msfvenom.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been fixed. Please check the [source](https://youtu.be/IU26QC3NDvo)

```
cd metasploit-framework;
sed -i '13,15 {s/^/#/}' /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/hrr_rb_ssh-0.4.2/lib/hrr_rb_ssh/transport/encryption_algorithm/functionable.rb; sed -i '14 {s/^/#/}' /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/hrr_rb_ssh-0.4.2/lib/hrr_rb_ssh/transport/server_host_key_algorithm/ecdsa_sha2_nistp256.rb; sed -i '14 {s/^/#/}' /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/hrr_rb_ssh-0.4.2/lib/hrr_rb_ssh/transport/server_host_key_algorithm/ecdsa_sha2_nistp384.rb; sed -i '14 {s/^/#/}' /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/hrr_rb_ssh-0.4.2/lib/hrr_rb_ssh/transport/server_host_key_algorithm/ecdsa_sha2_nistp521.rb;
clear;echo "Done...."
```

Use official Metasploit repository suggested by the source. Working for me.